# How to restart a program from a method

Tags: java, loops, methods, restart

I'm a beginner in Java and I am making a basic game for practice. I'm almost done, but I have one further obstacle to overcome.

I would like to know how to make the game loop on the `game()` method after pressing *no* as a choice when asked whether to end the game.

Here is my code:

```
private static void game() //game method
{
    //...

   int play = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null
                   ,"End"
                   , "Do you want to play again?"
                   , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE
                   ,JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION
                   , null
                   , again
                   , again[1]);
   //end of game

    if (play == 0)
        System.exit(0);//exit
    else
         /* what do I put here to restart the program in the same method(game()) 
            after pressing the No button on the JOptionPane???    */        
         System.out.println("Service not available");
```

To anybody who can help, I thank you very much!

Comment: Use a `while` or `do` loop to restart the game based on user input.

Comment: Given that your question is "Do you want to play again?" surely the restarting option should be *Yes* not *No*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to make it work you can do something like this :

```
private static void game()//game method
{
    boolean exit = false;
    while(!exit){
        //...int play = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Play Again?", "Do you want to play again?", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, again, again[1]);
       //end of game


        if (play == 0) {
            exit = true;
        }

    }          
        System.exit(0);//exit
```

But a better more professionnal approach would be to refactor your code, so you extract game logic and separate it from User dialog interaction.

Answer (score 3):

Given the current state of your program, the <s>easiest</s> <s>simplest</s> most <s>straightforward</s> readable method is recursion. Just call your game method again. Note that there's probably a recursion limit, so the loop is the recommended method, even if it does involve restructuring your code a bit.

```
else{
    game();
}
```

Loop method: declare `play` at the beginning and use a loop:

```
private static void game(){
    boolean play = true;
    while (play){
        //...
        //find out if user wants to play again
        //set play to false if player doesn't want to play anymore
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure recursion is the *easiest* option for a beginner (depending on depth of non-Java programming experience).

Comment: This solved my problem,,, calling the game method again!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Extract the `JOptionPane` part from your `game()` function code

```
int play=0;
do{
game();
play = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null
                   ,"End"
                   , "Do you want to play again?"
                   , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE
                   ,JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION
                   , null
                   , again
                   , again[1]); 
}while(play);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method which i am very sure will work in your program since it is something that i have done before. You'll use Desktop class of the system that will initiate the opening of the program. The program will look like this

```
public static void restart()
{
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    try {
        desktop.open(new File("name_of_your_jarfile.jar").getCanonicalFile());
// desktop.open(new File("name_of_your_exe.exe").getCanonicalFile());//for exe
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //if this happen try looking whether the name of your jar file is correct
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
private static void game() //game method
{
    //...

   int play = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null
                   ,"End"
                   , "Do you want to play again?"
                   , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE
                   ,JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION
                   , null
                   , again
                   , again[1]);
   //end of game
    if (play == 0)
        System.exit(0);//exit
    else
         /* what do I put here to restart the program in the same 
            after pressing the No button on the JOptionPane???    */        
         System.out.println("Service not available");  
       restart();//this will reopen your jar/exe file
       System.exit(0);
}
```